# Using a LVM Raid0 as a LVM Cache for / on Linux Mint

Tags: lvm, raid, caching

I have a pair of solid state drives (`/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdc`) and a hard drive (`/dev/sdb`). I would like to install the system to the hard drive, collect the SSD's into a Raid-0, and divide up that Raid-0 into swap space and cache for the hard drive.

I have got as far as installing the system to the hard drive with the mint installer, which produces:

```
sdb1: /boot/efi
sdb2: LVM2 PV --> mint-vg/root & mint-vg/swap_1
```

I am able also to build the raid. One thing I'm not sure about is whether to create multiple independent raid0 LV's for swap, cache and cache_meta  or to create a single contiguous LV on the raid, and divide that up into swap, cache and cache_meta.

I am able to move the default swap by modifying `/etc/fstab` to point to the new swap partition on the raid, and also create the cache pool. Reboots fine.

However, when linking the cache pool with the origin volume, I am no longer able to reboot, and drop into initramfs.

Is what I am doing supported by LVM? What is the right way to do this? Also, I would like to add LUKS to each drive/partition. Another post on here suggested RAID be the lowest level, then LUKS then LVM. But since I am using LVM to create the raid, I'm not sure how that affects the ordering.

Comment: "create a single contiguous LV on the raid, and divide that up into swap".  How would one do that?